# Is multiboxing allowed?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does Blizzard allow one user to play multiple accounts simultaneously? I know it is hard to verify if one or two players are currently playing, but would Blizzard ban my accounts if they knew I am multiboxing?

Comment: How would you be able to play two characters simultaneously? One mouse in each hand and only use the two skills on the mouse buttons?

Comment: Well, you could pull another account through all the quests or just trade items. Both require you to login with both accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a clear-cut yes-or-no answer from Blizzard, unfortunately you won't be able to get it at the present time; every recent inquiry about the subject on the official forums has been met with a generic "read the ToS" response.

There *was*, however, a post earlier this month by Blizzard representative Omrakos (in a forum thread that has since been deleted) that stated the following:

> Multiple copies from the same number of multiple computers with the same number of multiple accounts will be fine. You can't, to my knowledge, run more than 1 copy per pc simultaneously though. - Omrakos

Therefore, I think the best stance to take is such: there's no guarantee that multiboxing won't get you in trouble, but as long as you're using separate computers and not running multiple copies on a single machine, you're probably somewhat safe. That's still not a guarantee, however, and Blizzard could change their minds at any time.

Answer (score 2):

From a World of Warcraft and Starcraft 2 perspective, Blizzard has long allowed multiple accounts to play simultaneously.

The only concern is that you are careful if you are using software to play multiple characters at once simultaneously. Anything that emulates botting (keyboard emulation, packet duplicating, etc) will most likely result in bad times.